# Symfony 3 collection many to one , one to many, FK is null

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, symfony

I have a one to many colletion and 2 of those collections are working but the cursuri (name of variable) doesn't get the id of the disciplina is null.Laboratoare and referate is working why?I tried everything the only difference I see is the name.
Disciplina entity

```
  namespace AppBundle\Entity;


 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
  use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
   * @ORM\Table(name="disciplina")
* @Vich\Uploadable
 */
 class Disciplina
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
 *
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="banner_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
 *
 * @var File
 */
private $imageFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $imageName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $locatieLaborator;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $descriere;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $personal;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Referat",mappedBy="disciplina",cascade={"persist"})
 *
 */
private $referate;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Laborator",mappedBy="disciplina",cascade={"persist"})
 *
 */
private $laboratoare;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Curs",mappedBy="disciplina",cascade={"persist"})
 *
 */
private $cursuri;

public function addLaboratoare(Laborator $laborator){
    if($this->laboratoare->contains($laborator)){
        return;
    }

    $this->laboratoare->add($laborator);

    $laborator->setDisciplina($this);

    return $this;
}

public function removeLaboratoare(Laborator $laborator){
    if(!$this->laboratoare->contains($laborator)){
        return;
    }

    $this->laboratoare->remove($laborator);

    $laborator->setDisciplina(null);
}

public function addCursuri(Curs $curs){
    if($this->cursuri->contains($curs)){
        return;
    }

    $this->cursuri->add($curs);

    $curs->setDisciplina($this);

    return $this;
}

public function removeCursuri(Curs $curs){
    if(!$this->cursuri->contains($curs)){
        return;
    }

    $this->cursuri->remove($curs);

    $curs->setDisciplina(null);
}

public function addReferate(Referat $referat){
    if($this->referate->contains($referat)){
        return;
    }

    $this->referate->add($referat);

    $referat->setDisciplina($this);

    return $this;
}

public function removeReferate(Referat $Laboratoare){
    if(!$this->laboratoare->contains($Laboratoare)){
        return;
    }

    $this->laboratoare->remove($Laboratoare);

    $Laboratoare->setDisciplina(null);
}

/**
 * @return File
 */
public function getImageFile()
{
    return $this->imageFile;
}

/**
 * @param File $imageFile
 */
public function setImageFile(File $imageFile=null)
{
    $this->imageFile = $imageFile;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageName()
{
    return $this->imageName;
}

/**
 * @param string $imageName
 */
public function setImageName($imageName)
{
    $this->imageName = $imageName;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLocatieLaborator()
{
    return $this->locatieLaborator;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $locatieLaborator
 */
public function setLocatieLaborator($locatieLaborator)
{
    $this->locatieLaborator = $locatieLaborator;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDescriere()
{
    return $this->descriere;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $descriere
 */
public function setDescriere($descriere)
{
    $this->descriere = $descriere;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPersonal()
{
    return $this->personal;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $personal
 */
public function setPersonal($personal)
{
    $this->personal = $personal;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getReferate()
{
    return $this->referate;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $referate
 */
public function setReferate($referate)
{
    $this->referate = $referate;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLaboratoare()
{
    return $this->laboratoare;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $laboratoare
 */
public function setLaboratoare($laboratoare)
{
    $this->laboratoare = $laboratoare;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCursuri()
{
    return $this->cursuri;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $cursuri
 */
public function setCursuri($cursuri)
{
    $this->cursuri = $cursuri;
}


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->cursuri = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->laboratoare = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->referate = new ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

Cursuri entity

```
<?php
  /**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
    * User: Alex
 * Date: 2/6/2017
 * Time: 2:11 PM
 */

 namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

 /**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="curs")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
*/
 class Curs {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="discipline_files", fileNameProperty="fileName")
 *
 * @var File
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $fileName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $ordine;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $nume;

/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Disciplina",inversedBy="cursuri")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="disciplina_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
 */
private $disciplina;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDisciplina()
{
    return $this->disciplina;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $disciplina
 */
public function setDisciplina($disciplina)
{
    $this->disciplina = $disciplina;
}


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getNume()
{
    return $this->nume;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $nume
 */
public function setNume($nume)
{
    $this->nume = $nume;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFileName()
{
    return $this->fileName;
}

/**
 * @param string $fileName
 */
public function setFileName($fileName)
{
    $this->fileName = $fileName;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $file
 */
public function setFile(File $file=null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getOrdine()
{
    return $this->ordine;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $ordine
 */
public function setOrdine($ordine)
{
    $this->ordine = $ordine;
}

}
```

DisciplinaForm

```
   namespace AppBundle\Form;

   use AppBundle\Entity\Disciplina;
  use AppBundle\Entity\Fisier;
  use AppBundle\Entity\Laborator;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
 use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;

 class DisciplinaForm extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('imageFile', VichFileType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' =>'Banner',
            'allow_delete' => false, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => false, // not mandatory, default is true
        ])
        ->add("locatieLaborator")
        ->add("descriere")
        ->add("personal")
        ->add('laboratoare',CollectionType::class,[
            'entry_type'=>LaboratorForm::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'row'),
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'entry_options'  => array(
                'attr'      => array('class' => 'col-xs-4')
            ),
        ])
        ->add('cursuri',CollectionType::class,[
            'entry_type'=>CursForm::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'row'),
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'entry_options'  => array(
                'attr'      => array('class' => 'col-xs-4')
            ),
        ])
        ->add('referate',CollectionType::class,[
            'entry_type'=>ReferatForm::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'row'),
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'entry_options'  => array(
                'attr'      => array('class' => 'col-xs-4')
            ),
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        "data_class"=>Disciplina::class
    ]);
}
}
```

CursForm ,referate and laboratoare is the same form only name is changed

```
   <?php

   namespace AppBundle\Form;

  use AppBundle\Entity\Curs;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
 use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;

  class CursForm extends AbstractType
 {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add("nume")
        ->add("ordine")
        ->add('file', VichFileType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => false, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => false, // not mandatory, default is true
        ]);

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Curs::class
    ]);
}
}
```

Controller

```
      /**
    * @param $name
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
    * @Route("/adauga/disciplina",name="adauga_disciplina")
    */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
   {
    $form = $this->createForm(DisciplinaForm::class);

    // only handles data on POST
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $disciplina = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($disciplina);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            sprintf('Disciplina adaugata.')
        );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('adauga_disciplina');
    }

    return $this->render('disciplina/adauga_disciplina.html.twig',[
        'form'=>$form->createView()
    ]);
  }
```

This is almost impossible only the name is different and is not working.Laboratoare and referate is working but cursuri is not.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had to run those console commands

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm:clear-cache:result
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm:clear-cache:query
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm:clear-cache:metadata
```

Plus the stupid form was calling the method addCourse not addCourses and it gave me id null,for reall???????To verify this you can delete the setCourses method and it will tell you want method the form wants.

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you would be to just set up your relationships in the Entity classes, and then let the robots do all the rest of the job, by issuing:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Curs
```

This will make sure you have all the needed methods. Because, for example, you have that `setCursuri()` method which is not used. Instead you need `addCurs(\AppBundle\Entity\Curs $curs)`, `removeCurs(\AppBundle\Entity\Curs $curs)`, and `getCursuri()`.